# Changing Background color in Wordpress using class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I am using classima theme and there is no option to change the background color. I have tried this
`body { background-color: #080808; }`

but Its not working.
then I checked the theme documentation, and I found there some classes which are below-
13| Built-in CSS Classes (Advanced)

You can use the following built-in css classes if needed-

primary-color- set primary color

secondery-color- set secondery color

primary-bgcolor- set primary background color

secondery-bgcolor- set secondery background color

so I tried primary-bgcolor in CSS

i.e

it didnt worked.

I also tried this enter code here

`primary-bgcolor: #080808;`

notthing is working there please someone help me.

Comment: Can you post the URL, so we can check? Otherwise, it's going to be wild guesses.

Comment: Probably the problem is that you're not using ```!important```. You may try ```body { background-color: #080808 !important; }```